# counting lost packets with timestamp diff

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a table with an entry from every packet i receive from a particular device. The table has one column with the timestamp (clock tick) and every packet is received every half hour.
I want to count the lost packets.

My approach is calculate de difference of the timestamp on every consecutive row, and increment a counter if the difference is greater than 40 minutes.

But i'm not sure how to do it with a sql query.

I'm using MS Reporting Services 2008 R2 to show the count of lost packets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't know much about your data, but say the table is like this:

```
create table ClockTick
(
  packetTime datetime
)

insert into ClockTick select '01-Jan-2014 12:00'
insert into ClockTick select '01-Jan-2014 12:30'
insert into ClockTick select '01-Jan-2014 13:00'
insert into ClockTick select '01-Jan-2014 14:00'
insert into ClockTick select '01-Jan-2014 14:30'
insert into ClockTick select '01-Jan-2014 15:30'
insert into ClockTick select '01-Jan-2014 16:00'
insert into ClockTick select '01-Jan-2014 17:00'
```

You can get the required result, i.e. **3**, with a query like:

```
with ticks as
(
  select gapCounter = case
    when datediff(minute, t.packetTime, g.packetTime) >= 40 then 1
    else 0 
    end
  from ClockTick t
    cross apply (select top 1 g.packetTime
                from ClockTick g
                where t.packetTime < g.packetTime
                order by g.packetTime) g
)
select lostPackets = sum(gapCounter)
from ticks
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9ca8c/2).

For each row, this is finding the next received packet, then adding it to the total if the gap > 40 minutes.

Obviously you'll need to tweak for your table/column. If this isn't helpful, you'll need to supply some sample data and your expected results.

Comment: Thanks! It's really helpful. The table has one column named "Timestamp" and is a 64 bit integer field. The value is obtained from a System::DateTime object, calling the method Ticks (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks(v=vs.90).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1).
I think i must convert the int ticks to datetime so i can use the datediff as you did.

Comment: You're welcome! You could just adjust the query to be something like `...when g.[timestamp] - t.[timestamp] >= 24000000000 then 1 else 0...`, i.e. a difference of 24000000000 ticks is 40 minutes (I think; arithmetic might be wrong), if you don't want to muck around with your table.

Comment: I did that! Thanks a lot!